# vCard UUID - recognize and match vCard Instance

Tags: qr-code, vcf-vcard, rfc

I'm trying to let my phone recognize a vCard by scanning its QR code equivalent and make sure to NOT add a second contact if it already exists.

Step 1: create a vCard

Step 2: create the QR code

I ended up using RFC 6350 articles 6.7.6 and 7.1.1 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6350#section-6.7.6) and concluded that by putting in `UID:urn:uuid:f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6` "MUST match vCard instances"

To test it, I create a vCard with random data and added the UUID:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
UID:urn:uuid:77a01597-0603-40f3-8138-36deca8618da
N:test Family Name;First Name;;;
FN:TestFirst Name
TITLE:Your job title
EMAIL:emailaddress@example.com
ADR;HOME:;;123, avenue des Champs-Élysées;Paris;Île-de-France;75008;France
TEL;TYPE=cell:+33 123456789
URL:http://example.com
END:VCARD
```

Testing it at https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ does not provide the expected result.

**Expected result**

Scanning the QR code of the vCard twice does not add a second contact (it recognizes the first)

**Actual result**

It creates to contacts.

What am I doing wrong? Should I do something with the described `UID-param` and `UID-value` as well? If yes, then how?

Many thanks!

Comment: One thing that's definitely wrong with your vcard is that there's two `UID` properties.

Comment: You're right, it was a copy-paste. I changed it.